# IPMI and SNMP - Concept like location and functionality

Tags: snmp

I have a question that is basically clarification of concepts:

I know IPMI "...provides management and monitoring capabilities..." [copy/paste from wiki]

And SNMP "...exposes management data in the form of variables on the managed systems, which describe the system configuration...." [also copy/paste from wiki]

After studying IPMI for a while, it seems that it can exist in a layer very close to the hardware, making it independent of O.S.

On the other hand, SNMP runs in a more "higher level", much closer to the O.S.

**My understand is that: Both provide machine information, but IPMI will work independent of anything (like O.S.). While SNMP is just a way for the O.S. to expose machine information where it is sitting on.**

Is the above statement correct? Or am I completely mistaken and I need better understand of both concepts? If that's the case, would you care to clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read your IPMI article carefully, you will see that IPMI is primarily used for PCs and servers, and it is a specification for out-of-band management of a system. IPMI also requires specialized hardware.

On the other hand, SNMP is a software specification which is used across a wide variety of hardware, usually in the OS, and it is primarily used in-band. SNMP can be set to send traps to an SNMP server, or it can be polled by an SNMP server or application.